# Can't borrow File from &mut self (error msg: cannot move out of borrowed content)

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

pub struct Foo {
    maybe_file: Option<File>,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn init(&mut self) {
        self.maybe_file = Some(File::open("/proc/uptime").unwrap());
    }

    pub fn print(&mut self) {
        let mut file = self.maybe_file.unwrap();
        let mut s = String::new();
        file.read_to_string(&mut s).unwrap();
        println!("Uptime: {}", s);
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Compiling this will give me:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:14:24
   |
14 |         let mut file = self.maybe_file.unwrap();
   |                        ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Why is this happening? What do I do to solve it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`self` has type `&mut Foo` in `print`, that is, it is a borrowed mutable reference to a value of type `Foo`. Types in Rust move ownership by default, that is, taking something by-value will statically invalidate the source and stop the programmer from using it again (unless it is reinitialized). In this case, [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) has the signature:

```
impl Option<T> {
    fn unwrap(self) -> T { ...
```

That is, it is taking the `Option` value by-value and thus trying to consume ownership of it. Hence, `self.maybe_file.unwrap()` is trying to consume the data in `maybe_file` which would leave `self` pointing to partially invalid data (it is illegal to use the `maybe_file` field after that). There's no way the compiler can enforce this with borrowed references which have to be valid always as they could point anywhere, so it is illegal to move out.

Fortunately, one can avoid this problem: the [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) method creates an `Option<&T>` out of an `&Option<T>` and the [`as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut) method creates an `Option<&mut T>` out of an `&mut Option<T>`. The resulting `Option` is then no longer behind a reference and so it is legal to consume it via `unwrap`:

```
let mut file = self.maybe_file.as_mut().unwrap();
```

This differs  slightly because `file` has type `&mut File` instead of `File`, but fortunately `&mut File` is all that is necessary for the rest of the code.

Another approach to making this work is using manual pattern matching:

```
match self.maybe_file {
    Some(ref mut file)  => println!(...),
    None => panic!("error: file was missing")
}
```

This is doing exactly the same thing as the `.as_mut().unwrap()` just more explicitly: the `ref mut` is create a reference pointing directly into the memory occupied by `self.maybe_file`, just like `as_mut`.