# Reference to unwrapped property fails: use of partially moved value: `self`

Tags: rust, structure

I try to send an unwrapped string reference to a static method implemented for a struct. Here is a simplified code:

```
fn main() {
    let a = A {p: Some("p".to_string())};
    a.a();
}

struct A {
    p: Option<String>
}

impl A {
    fn a(self) -> Self {
        Self::b(&self.p.unwrap());
        self
    }
    fn b(b: &str) {
        print!("b: {}", b)
    }
}
```

It fails:

```
error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `self`
  --> src/main.rs:14:13
   |
13 |             Self::b(&self.p.unwrap());
   |                      ------ value moved here
14 |             self
   |             ^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `self.p` has type `std::option::Option<std::string::String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I think implementing the `Copy` trait is not a solution. **How can I unwrap `p` and pass it as a `&str` to `b` in that context?**

I changed my code as suggested in [Can't borrow File from &mut self (error msg: cannot move out of borrowed content)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034646/cant-borrow-file-from-mut-self-error-msg-cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content):

```
fn main() {
    let a = A {p: Some("p".to_string())};
    a.a();
}

struct A {
    p: Option<String>
}

impl A {
    fn a(self) -> Self {
        let c = self.p.as_ref().unwrap();
        Self::b(&c);
        self
    }
    fn b(b: &str) {
        print!("b: {}", b)
    }
}
```

Which results in a different error:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `self` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:15:13
   |
13 |             let c = self.p.as_ref().unwrap();
   |                     ------ borrow of `self.p` occurs here
14 |             Self::b(&c);
15 |             self
   |             ^^^^ move out of `self` occurs here
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/31233938/155423 and the [function declaration for `unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap).

Comment: `as_ref()` would probably be better here than the duplicate's suggestion, since you want a `&str` not a `&mut str` or `&mut String`.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I tried to add `as_ref()` but it still does not work (maybe I misunderstood something) http://play.integer32.com/?gist=d6399128af86ae76f2b880dd711f7849&version=stable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in [Can't borrow File from &mut self (error msg: cannot move out of borrowed content)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034646/cant-borrow-file-from-mut-self-error-msg-cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content), you can't call `unwrap` on a borrowed value because `unwrap` takes ownership of the value.

Changing to `as_ref` borrows from the value `self`. You are not allowed to move a value (which includes returning that value) while any references to it are outstanding. That means you need to constrain the life of the borrow to end before the value needs to be moved:

```
fn a(self) -> Self {
    {
        let c = self.p.as_ref().unwrap();
        Self::b(c);
    }
    self
}
```

---

It may be an artifact of your example, but the code is pretty strange. I'd have written it as

```
impl A {
    fn a(self) -> Self {
        self.b();
        self
    }

    fn b(&self) {
        print!("b: {}", self.p.as_ref().unwrap())
    }
}
```

Or

```
impl A {
    fn a(&self) {
        print!("a: {}", self.p.as_ref().unwrap())
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's probably easier just to put it all in one line, like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d0e5c2a66513613d5136deab406793d1&version=stable&backtrace=0) (`Self::b(self.p.as_ref().unwrap())`) to avoid the rather ugly block.

Comment: @Aurora0001 good point! The block is more versatile and so it's good to know.

Comment: @Shepmaster "the code is pretty strange" Yes! It's because, it's oversimplified to just display the problem I was encountering. Anyway, thanks!